# How to get a table name from a model in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Is it possible to get model's table name? I see that it's possible to get it from *ModelStruct* but I don't know how to do it correctly. I didn't find any initializations for this structure.

```
user := User{}
tableName := db...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
tableName := db.NewScope(model).GetModelStruct().TableName(db)
```

Update:
Shorter

```
tableName := db.NewScope(model).TableName()
```

Comment: it could be shorter: `tableName := db.NewScope(model).TableName()`

Comment: The accepted answer does not work for the library at https://gorm.io/

Comment: The accepted answer works for v1, for v2 check the answer above.

Comment: db.NewScope doesnt exists.

Answer (score 13):

For Gorm v2, according to https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3603,
you can do:

```
stmt := &gorm.Statement{DB: DB}
stmt.Parse(&ColumnStruct2{})
stmt.Schema.Table
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method for Gorm v2, without passing a DB object.

```
type WeatherStation struct{}
s, _ := schema.Parse(&WeatherStation{}, &sync.Map{}, schema.NamingStrategy{})
fmt.Println(s.Table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue to find table name when trying to setup a scope where two tables can have the same column name. Below snippet works for me.

```
func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    if db.Statement.Model == nil {
        return db.WithContext(ctx).Where("deleted_at IS NULL")
    }
    model := db.Statement.Model
    db.Statement.Parse(model)
    tableName := db.Statement.Schema.Table
    return db.WithContext(ctx).Where(fmt.Sprintf("%s.deleted_at IS NULL", tableName))
}
```