# Gorm get column name

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following model in gorm

```
type Person struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Name      string         `gorm:"not null,type:text"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index,->"`
}
```

Is it possible to get the **column name**? I want the column name that gorm will generate

Comment: Dear @Rodrigo, Just to clarify. Would you like to get the column name or the value of the `json` tag?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov I want to pass `CreatedAt` and get the name which gorm  will use, in this case I know that is `created_at`, despite the JSON, I will update the question

Comment: Hello, @Rodrigo! Thank you for the update! Could you please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039884)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Possible solution

The solution is to retrieve («parse») the schema from the model.
Please, note: from the model — not from a «physical» database.

### References

- [How to get a map[string]string of Structure/Model Fields and DB Columns? · Issue #5114 · go-gorm/gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5114).

  - The solution comment: **[tzinckgraf](https://github.com/tzinckgraf)** commented [on Mar 4](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5114#issuecomment-1059285907).
- [How do I get the column name from the model struct field · Issue #4497 · go-gorm/gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4497).
- Slightly related question. [go - How to get a table name from a model in gorm? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999441/how-to-get-a-table-name-from-a-model-in-gorm).

### Draft example program

#### `go.mod`

```
module gorm/example

go 1.18

require (
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0
    gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8
)

require (
    github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/now v1.1.4 // indirect
)
```

#### `go.sum`

```
github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 h1:t6JiXgmwXMjEs8VusXIJk2BXHsn+wx8BZdTaoZ5fu7I=
github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0/go.mod h1:TIyPZe4MgqvfeYDBFedMoGGpEw/LqOeaOT+nhxU+yHo=
github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0 h1:K317FqzuhWc8YvSVlFMCCUb36O/S9MCKRDI7QkRKD/E=
github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0/go.mod h1:h+uFLlag+Qp1Va5pdKtLDYj+kHp5pxUVkryuEj+Srlc=
github.com/jinzhu/now v1.1.4 h1:tHnRBy1i5F2Dh8BAFxqFzxKqqvezXrL2OW1TnX+Mlas=
github.com/jinzhu/now v1.1.4/go.mod h1:d3SSVoowX0Lcu0IBviAWJpolVfI5UJVZZ7cO71lE/z8=
gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8 h1:h8sGJ+biDgBA1AD1Ha9gFCx7h8npU7AsLdlkX0n2TpE=
gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8/go.mod h1:l2lP/RyAtc1ynaTjFksBde/O8v9oOGIApu2/xRitmZk=
```

#### Program (`main.go`)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Person struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Name      string         `gorm:"not null,type:text"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index,->"`
}

func main() {
    s, err := schema.Parse(&Person{}, &sync.Map{}, schema.NamingStrategy{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse schema")
    }

    m := make(map[string]string)
    for _, field := range s.Fields {
        dbName := field.DBName
        modelName := field.Name
        m[modelName] = dbName
    }

    fmt.Println("Model to schema field name map:", m)
    fmt.Println("CreatedAt field is mapped to", m["CreatedAt"], "column")
}
```

#### Build

```
$ go build main.go
```

#### Run

```
$ ./main
```

##### Output

```
Model to schema field name map: map[CreatedAt:created_at DeletedAt:deleted_at ID:id Name:name UpdatedAt:updated_at]
CreatedAt field is mapped to created_at column
```

Answer (score 1):

use tag like this:

> gorm:"column:uid"

```
type UserInfo struct {
    Uid       int       `json:"uid" gorm:"column:uid" form:"uid"` 
    Uname     string    `json:"uname" gorm:"column:uname" form:"uname"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I want the column name that gorm will generate

Comment: Whats the exact use case here @Rodrigo?

Comment: See if this can help https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name